# Why does MySQL stop using an index for a join when I select non-indexed fields in the field list

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `temporal_expressions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dated_obj_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`dated_obj_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`start_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`end_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`lock_version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `te_search` (`dated_obj_type`,`dated_obj_id`,`start_date`,`end_date`),
KEY `te_calendar`   (`dated_obj_type`,`dated_obj_id`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`start_time`,`end_time`),
KEY `te_search_wday` (`dated_obj_type`,`dated_obj_id`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`wday`),
KEY `te_calendar_wday` (`dated_obj_type`,`dated_obj_id`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`wday`),
KEY `te_index` (`wday`,`dated_obj_type`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`dated_obj_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8162445 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `asset_blocks` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`block_type` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`spaces_left` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`provider_note` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`extra_data` text,
`lock_version` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`service_provider_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `type` (`type`,`id`),
KEY `service_provider_id` (`service_provider_id`,`type`,`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=516867 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

If I run explain on this query (note that I am only selecting fields in the te_calendar_wday index from temporal_expressions) it uses the index for the join as expected

```
EXPLAIN SELECT asset_blocks.*, temporal_expressions.id,
temporal_expressions.dated_obj_type, temporal_expressions.dated_obj_id,
temporal_expressions.start_date, temporal_expressions.end_date,
temporal_expressions.start_time
FROM `asset_blocks`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `temporal_expressions`
ON `temporal_expressions`.dated_obj_id = `asset_blocks`.id 
  AND `temporal_expressions`.dated_obj_type = 'AssetBlock'
WHERE ( temporal_expressions.start_date <= '2010-11-25' 
AND temporal_expressions.end_date >= '2010-11-01'
AND temporal_expressions.start_time < 1000 AND temporal_expressions.end_time > 1200 
AND temporal_expressions.wday IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
AND asset_blocks.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) )

1 SIMPLE temporal_expressions range    te_search,te_calendar,te_search_wday,te_calendar_wday,te_index te_calendar_wday 272 NULL 9 Using where; Using index
1 SIMPLE asset_blocks eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 lb_production.temporal_expressions.dated_obj_id 1
```

However, if I run this query (note that I have added a non-indexed field to the field list) it no longer uses the index (it uses a join buffer). Is this intentional or am I missing something?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT asset_blocks.*, temporal_expressions.id,
temporal_expressions.dated_obj_type, temporal_expressions.dated_obj_id,
temporal_expressions.start_date, temporal_expressions.end_date,
temporal_expressions.start_time, temporal_expressions.created_at
FROM `asset_blocks`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `temporal_expressions`
ON `temporal_expressions`.dated_obj_id = `asset_blocks`.id 
  AND `temporal_expressions`.dated_obj_type = 'AssetBlock'
WHERE ( temporal_expressions.start_date <= '2010-11-25' 
AND temporal_expressions.end_date >= '2010-11-01'
AND temporal_expressions.start_time < 1000 AND temporal_expressions.end_time > 1200 
AND temporal_expressions.wday IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
AND asset_blocks.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) )


1 SIMPLE asset_blocks range PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 NULL 9 Using where
1 SIMPLE temporal_expressions range te_search,te_calendar,te_search_wday,te_calendar_wday,new_te_index te_search 272 NULL 9 Using where; Using join buffer
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure if this is the case here, but:

If you select only indexed fields, MySQL can answer the whole query out of the index and does not even load the table data file.

If you select a field that is not indexed, it has to load the table data.

When making its execution plan, in certain cases (see comment) MySQL decides to do a full table scan although an index is present. This is because it's much quicker to read all data blindly than to look up every entry in the index *and then* read the data.

Comment: Ok, I deleted that statement about the 50% because I looked it up and on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/where-optimizations.html it says: Each table index is queried, and the best index is used unless the optimizer believes that it is more efficient to use a table scan. At one time, a scan was used based on whether the best index spanned more than 30% of the table, but a fixed percentage no longer determines the choice between using an index or a scan. The optimizer now is more complex and bases its estimate on additional factors such as table size, number of rows, and I/O block size.